# How to start a daemon process which can use some django feature?

Tags: python, django

I have a django project run on the server.

Now need to write another long running process(not web server). I hope that the process can use some feature that my django project already provided.

Like ORM. For example,  I hope  to query the db with models I defined in django

So how to do it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple way would likely be to write a [django management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/) and use something like cron to call this script at a given time interval.